# How to define canonical bundle of a complex orbifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I have been told that the canonical divisor of an orbifold is defined by closing the canonical divisor of the smooth locus. However, since a real orbifold has singularities of codimension at least two, a complex orbifold can have a singular locus complex codimension 1, so it might contribute components to the divisor. How then should we define the canonical bundle?

Comment: Orbifolds can only have singularities in codimension at least 2. They are locally given by finite group acting linearly on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ and taking quotients.